# DB2 SQL involving LISTAGG

Tags: sql, db2

I have a dataset like below

```
  DEPT_ID  EMP_NM   STATUS_DATE    LEFT_FLAG      STATUS_CHANGE
    1       ABC      20200131        0            N
    1       DEF      20200204        0            N
    1       DEF      20200504        0            Y
    1       XYZ      20201210        0            N
    1       MNO      20201210        0            N
    1       DEF      20201230        1            N
    1       XYZ      20201230        0            Y
    1       PQR      20210123        0            N
    1       ABC      20210228        1            N
    1       XYZ      20210228        1            N
```

Now I want to generate the output like below

```
  DEPT_ID  EMP_NM               STATUS_DATE    
    1       ABC                  20200131        
    1       ABC,DEF              20200204  
    1       ABC,DEF              20200504      
    1       ABC,DEF,XYZ,MNO      20201210        
    1       ABC,XYZ,MNO          20201230        
    1       ABC,XYZ,MNO,PQR      20210123        
    1       MNO,PQR              20210228
```

I tried with LISTAGG, but unable to eliminate the duplicates and also unable to remove when LEFT_FLAG=1

Comment: Your logic is not 100% clear.  The rows are not cumulative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of employees at each time.  The status flag appears to have to relevance.

This version should work in DB2:

```
select dept_id, status_date, listagg(emp_nm, ',') within group (order by emp_nm)
from (select t.dept_id, t.status_date, t2.status_date as status_date_2, t2.left_flag, t2.emp_nm,
              row_number() over (partition by t.status_date, t2.dept_id, t2.emp_nm order by t2.status_date desc) as seqnum
      from (select dept_id, status_date
            from t 
            group by dept_id, status_date
           ) t left join
           t t2
           on t2.dept_id = t.dept_id and t2.status_date <= t.status_date
     ) tt2
where seqnum = 1 and left_flag = 0
group by dept_id, status_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=713a7fb9293020a59122113324a62d36) is a db<>fiddle.

This version doesn't because the correlation clause is nested too deeply, alas, for DB2:

```
select t.dept_id, t.status_date,
       (select listagg(t2.emp_nm, ',') within group (order by t2.emp_nm)
        from (select t2.emp_nm,
                     row_number() over (partition by t2.dept_id, t2.emp_nm order by t2.status_date desc) as seqnum
              from t t2
              where t2.status_date <= t.status_date and
                    t2.dept_id = t.dept_id
             ) t2
        where t2.seqnum = 1 and t2.left_flag = 0
       ) as emps
from t
group by dept_id, status_date;
```

Comment: does it support in db2 v11.x ?

Comment: Should work in DB2 LUW 10.5+. `LISTAGG()` doesn't have underscore in DB2.

Comment: It didn't found t2.left_flag. As it is not there within t2

Comment: it is giving me same value in emps for all row

Comment: It is still not handling the left_flag. means for the left_flag I want to remove those emps

Comment: @KoushikChandra .  . . The  first query does that.  The SQL fiddle illustrate exactly that happening.